# Use d3.selection.brush to highlight circles in a scatterplot

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to use the selection.brush to highlight a bunch of circles in a scatterplot and don't know where to start. I have alreday created the scatterplot and bound the circle to my data.

Are all the three functions (brushstart, brush, brushmove) mentioned in mbostock's documentation necessary? And how do I set the the extent?

Comment: Did you see [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063663)?

Comment: I did but could not figure out what parts of the code needed for a single scatterplot :\

Comment: It's entirely driven by the data. If you pass in data with only one column you get only one plot. You should be able to work from there.